# Active X not rendering print control

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, activex, ssrs-2012

I have an internal web page (edge) that links to an SSRS report (IE mode) when i click the link and it opens the SSRS report the active x print button is not there, however when i hit the refresh button the print button appears.

I think the active x control is not triggering properly when it opens the tab but cant find any help on my suspicion.

I have tried my intranet page in IE mode going to IE mode but this did not work.

Comment: As far as I know, Edge IE mode [support ActiveX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode#ie-mode-supports-the-following-internet-explorer-functionality) controls except Silverlight. I want to know whether this issue will also occur in IE11? I found [a similar case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/573129/edge-ie-mode-activex-only-works-when-manually-turn.html), I think it may be the cause of this issue.

Comment: thanks for this reference. i've shortened it down to see the effect hopefully it works